# String to date in Java correct

Tags: java, date

Hi this is simple code:

```js
//string data contain format which i must have for example 1990-12-12.
String data = "1990-12-12"
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result;
result = df.parse(data);
System.out.println("New date format: "+result);
```

Output:

```
[Wed Dec 12 00:00:00 CET 1990]
```

It is possible to have on the output this : **1990-12-12** in date format?

Comment: Sure, just use the same format object: `df.format(result)`

Comment: `System.out.println(df.format(data));`

Comment: Doesn't format() come before parse() in JavaDocs?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do the output using the same [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) using [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29):

```
System.out.println( df.format( result ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The date you have in your `Date` variable is correct. What you print is a `String`. I suppose you print it with `System.out.println(result);`, which returns a default format for the locale you use. If you want to print it with another format, you can use the `format()` method of your `SimpleDateFormat`: `System.out.println(df.format(result));`.